# Version Magic in Linux?

Tags: linux

Recently I have encountered new words "Version magic" & "Partition magic" in Linux. Can anyone brief me what do they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "magic" in these phrases stands for "[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)", or "magic bytes".

"Version magic" refers to a file type that contains version information in the magic bytes. For example, the Linux kernel typically contains version information there.

"Partition magic" refers to the magic bytes contained in a partition table to identify the partition contained, for example, as displayed by `fdisk`. For example, you can find information about one particular type of partition table used by the MBR format [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning).

Comment: may i know the commands for checking these files and can we edit these?

Comment: @user3148499 Well, you can edit anything you like, but it doesn't mean it's a good idea :-) `fdisk -l` displays a lot of information about the data contained in your partition table, and `file` can read magic bytes (and perhaps more) for most things. If you want to read the bytes raw, for example, as hex, consider using `xxd`. You can write specific bytes using `dd` with the appropriate argument to `offset`.

Comment: I'd rather use `blkid` than `fdisk` to get partition information unless I really want to know the start/end LBA of a given partition. And `fdisk` does not read GPT....

Comment: @solsTiCe `blkid` is Linux specific, which is why I preferred to mention something more generalisable (MBR + fdisk). But sure, `blkid` is also quite capable. :-)